# How to access CookieContainer in HTTPClient instance created via HTTPClientFactory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In an ASP.NET Core 2.2 web API, I want to be able to access `CookieContainer` from a named `HttpClient` and not sure how to configure this.

In Startup.cs:

```
        services
            .AddHttpClient("MyClient")                
            .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpClientHandler
            {
                UseProxy = false,
                //CookieContainer = ???
            });
```

In controller:

```
public MyController(IOptions<IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
{
   _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
}

public async Task<ObjectResult> Get<T>(string endpoint)
{
   var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("MyClient");
   var response = await httpClient.GetAsync($"{Settings.Url}/{endpoint}");
   //httpClient.CookieContainer ???
}
```

It's pretty straight forward while using just an instance of `HttpClient` and associating a `CookieContainer` with its `MessageHandler`, e.g.:

```
var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { CookieContainer = cookieContainer };
var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = "http://foo.com/api"}
var result = await client.PostAsync("", content);
//read response cookies
var cookies = cookieContainer.GetCookies(new Uri("http://foo.com/api"));
```

Wondering how I can read response cookies but via an instance of `HttpClient` created using `IHttpClientFactory`.

Comment: hmm you last example is a bit confusing, x.GetCookies, where is x defined? don't you mean cookieContainer?

Comment: corrected - it is cookieContainer for sure.

Answer (score 3):

That's not `CookieContainer` instance, but you can access raw cookies in response header:

```
var cookies = response.Headers.GetValues("Set-Cookie");
```

And you can try to call your request in the browser with open [Mozilla dev tool](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) to see if it is truly there.

[image: Mozilla Developer tools]